# How to find out the exact position of the mouse cursor when the user clicks a button in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to set the top and left px numbers for a div based on this data. How might one go about doing this?

So basically when a user clicks on this element. I have a `showcontent` function which shows/hides content. But I need to set the top by finding the position of cursor

```
function ShowContent(d) {  
    document.getElementById(d).style.display = "block";  
}
```

Comment: i felt there is some existing answer for the same question. Why dont you try those answers before asking again. also if you wish to read more, try this one . http://www.kvcodes.com/2014/03/get-exact-top-left-position-mouse-pointer-location-using-jquery/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example is based on the jQuery javascript library.

```
$("#button").click(function(e){
        alert("X is: "+e.pageX+" \n Y is:"+e.pageY);
});
```

**Online demo** here: http://jsfiddle.net/pGdbD/1/

Try clicking in different parts of the button

Comment: You should only answer with jquery if the question is marked as such, unless you add a disclaimer.

Comment: totally agree, i didn't realize it was not tagged as jQuery, but i did add a disclaimer a few minutes ago.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`event.pageX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.pageX) and [`event.pageY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.pageY) properties of the Event object to find out where the mouse was when the event took place.  For example:

```
document.getElementById('yourDiv').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    console.log('X: ' + event.pageX + ' Y: ' + event.pageY);
});
```

Obviously your actual code would be more complex, using `attachEvent` for IE, for instance, but this should show you how it's done.

---

**Edit** As Juan quite rightly reminds me, `pageX/Y` are not set in Internet Explorer.  The following is adapted from the jQuery source code, and works round this problem:

```
function(event) {
    var x, y;

    if ( event.pageX == null && event.clientX != null ) {
        var doc = document.documentElement,
            body = document.body;

        x = event.clientX + (doc && doc.scrollLeft || body && body.scrollLeft || 0) - (doc && doc.clientLeft || body && body.clientLeft || 0);
        y = event.clientY + (doc && doc.scrollTop  || body && body.scrollTop  || 0) - (doc && doc.clientTop  || body && body.clientTop  || 0);
    } else {
        x = event.pageX;
        y = event.pageY;
    }

    console.log('X: ' + x + ' Y: ' + y);
}
```

Comment: pageX/Y don't exist in IE, you have to use clientX/Y and account for scrolling. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535863(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Juan Quite right too -- many thanks for reminding me of this. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use jquery or another lib, you need to look at this page http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html to handle it cross browser. It involves the following properties: Event.clientX or Event.pageX

Otherwise jquery's event has a pageX and pageY properties.

Most libraries have something to do this for you.

Ext-Core: Event.getPageX() http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/EventManager.html#method-Ext.EventObject-getPageX

jquery: http://api.jquery.com/event.pageX/

Comment: +1 for quirksmode link.  Invaluable resource when trying to figure out mouse coordinates/events.